# which camera is better to use with ROS: kinect or astra?

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-kinetic, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every one

I am working on a project that needs a camera with a depth sensor and I am wondering which one of these tow cameras will be better for me to use the xbox 360 kinetic or the astra pro

and which one is more supported in ROS or there is no difference ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270274/which-camera-is-better-to-use-with-ros:-kinect-or-astra-?/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are both fully supported with drivers readily available. For the Orbbec Astra drivers, see [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/astra_camera). For the Kinect 360 see [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera). The better camera is simply the one with the better performance characteristics that suit your application. This includes the depth image size, depth range, field of view etc. I'm not sure what an Astra costs, but 360 Kinects can be picked up very cheap second hand.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1